# Python matrix add diagonal elements

Tags: python

I need to make a small program that will take a 4x4 matrix and add the diagonal of the of the columns and rows.

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

Like this would add 1+2+3+4.

Sorry for being vague, this is what I came up with for adding a matrix by each column straight down. I also have not been using numpy yet.

```
matrix = [1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12] #Assume a list is given
total = 0
    for column in range(0, len(matrix[0])):
        for row in range(0, len(matrix)):
            total += matrix[row][column]
        print("Sum for column " + str(column) + " is " + str(total))
        total = 0   #Reset total to zero before restarting count
```

I'm not 100% where to start with this so any ideas would be great. My teacher told us *offset* as a hint.

Comment: It would help if you showed us what you've got already and where you're stuck.  As it is, this is a fairly straight-forward problem which makes this look like a "Would you please do my homework for me?" kind of question.  Generally, people around here are a lot more receptive to questions where we feel like we're helping you learn instead of just feeding you answers.

Comment: If any of the answers here were able to solve your problem, please make sure to "accept" the best one by clicking the green check-mark on the left.

Answer (score 3):

The diagonal elements are at the same row-column coordinates:

```
matrix = [[1,2,3,4],
          [1,2,3,4],
          [1,2,3,4],
          [1,2,3,4]]
answer = sum(matrix[i][i] for i in range(len(matrix)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple using numpy

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> matrix = [[1,2,3,4],
              [1,2,3,4],
              [1,2,3,4],
              [1,2,3,4]]
>>> sum(np.diag(matrix))
10
```